# Change build template in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-9.0

How do I change the build configuration template for a project?

Previously my TeamCity project was using a generic build template which is used by 5 other projects. I created a new template by copying an existing template and made changes that are relevant to my project. Now I cannot find a way to using this template in my TeamCity project.

Is there a easier way other than creating a new build configuration and inheriting the newly created build template?

Answer (score 14):

Following is mentioned in [TeamCity doc](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Configuration+Template#BuildConfigurationTemplate-Associatingbuildconfigurationswithtemplates):

> - You can create new build configurations based on a template.
> - You can associate any number of existing build configurations with a    template: there's the Associate with Template option available
>     from    the Actions button at top right corner of the screen.

So, **Option 1** you have is to to go through each Build Configuration, detach from old template and attach to the new one.

**Option 2** you might want to consider will be to modify your existing template with the new settings instead of creating a copy. This might be suitable if you are only planning on using one template.

**Option 3** is to use [TeamCity API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings) which allows to read, detach and attach a build configuration from/to a template:

```
GET/DELETE/PUT http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/template
```

Comment: I think you mean "Hidden" not mentioned. Ta btw.

Answer (score 3):

There is an **option 4**: If you have the settings in a git-repo, then you can checkout that git-repo, search and replace all ref occurrences of the template-id with new template-id found in

```
<settings ref="old-template-id">
```

Then commit and push the new xml files to teamcity repo.

After around 3-4 minutes, the new configuration is applied by teamcity automatically

Comment: Awesome! As I had access to the teamcity directories, I just changed it in the config files located in /config/projects/[ProjectName]/buildTypes/[BuildConfigName].xml